# BASH: Display two files side by side simultaneously

Tags: bash, text, awk

I'm working on a bash script, and I want to print two files side by side.
One file is filled with IPv4 addresses and the other one is filled with IPv6 addresses. 
I tried,

```
pr -mtw $WIDTH $FILE1 $FILE2
```

but it cut the output.

```
┌────┤IPV4├─────┬─────────────────┤IPV6├────────────────┐
 224.0.0.1       2001:0db8:0000:
 192.0.2.128     ff02::1
 192.0.2.128     2001:0db8:0000:
 192.0.2.128     ::
                 2001:0db8:0000:
                 2001:db8:0:0:0:
                 2001:db8::ff00:
                 0000:0000:0000:
                 ::1
                 fe80::
                 ::ffff:192.0.2.
                 ::192.0.2.128
```

I also tried,

```
paste $FILE1 $FILE2  | awk '$1=$1' OFS='\t '
```

and the output was,

```
┌────┤IPV4├─────┬─────────────────┤IPV6├────────────────┐
224.0.0.1    2001:0db8:0000:0042:0000:8a2e:0370:7334
192.0.2.128  ff02::1
192.0.2.128  2001:0db8:0000:0000:0000:ff00:0042:8329
192.0.2.128  ::
2001:0db8:0000:0000:0000:ff00:0042:8329
2001:db8:0:0:0:ff00:42:8329
2001:db8::ff00:42:8329
0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001
::1
fe80::
::ffff:192.0.2.128
::192.0.2.128
```

I want the output to be something like,

```
┌────┤IPV4├─────┬─────────────────┤IPV6├────────────────┐
 224.0.0.1       2001:0db8:0000:0042:0000:8a2e:0370:7334
 192.0.2.128     ff02::1
 192.0.2.128     2001:0db8:0000:0000:0000:ff00:0042:8329
 192.0.2.128     ::
                 2001:0db8:0000:0000:0000:ff00:0042:8329
                 2001:db8:0:0:0:ff00:42:8329
                 2001:db8::ff00:42:8329
                 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001
                 ::1
                 fe80::
                 ::ffff:192.0.2.128
                 ::192.0.2.128
```

FILE1:

```
 224.0.0.1
 192.0.2.128
 192.0.2.128
 192.0.2.128
```

FILE2:

```
 2001:0db8:0000:0042:0000:8a2e:0370:7334
 ff02::1
 2001:0db8:0000:0000:0000:ff00:0042:8329
 ::
 2001:0db8:0000:0000:0000:ff00:0042:8329
 2001:db8:0:0:0:ff00:42:8329
 2001:db8::ff00:42:8329
 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001
 ::1
 fe80::
 ::ffff:192.0.2.128
 ::192.0.2.128
```

**Note that there is a space at the beginning of each line.**
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share the contents of individual files separately for tryout?

Comment: Can you show the input files? or an example of them? `paste` works for me, but I'm not sure what you have as input.

Comment: You want the final output with space or without it?

Comment: I want the output with space. I think this is the answer, you commented before, but with a space.
`paste <(tr -d ' ' <"$FILE1") <(tr -d ' ' <"${TMP}/$FILE2") | awk -v FS='\t' '{printf(" %-15s %s\n",$1,$2)}`

Comment: @xToNouSou: refer my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine

```
paste "$FILE1" "$FILE2" | awk -F'\t' '{printf("%-16s%s\n", $1, $2)}'
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `awk`, `tr` and `GNU paste` command:-

```
$ paste file1 file2 | awk -v FS='\t' '{printf("%-15s %s\n",$1,$2)}' | \
            awk '{sub(/^/, " ", $0)}1'

 224.0.0.1       2001:0db8:0000:0042:0000:8a2e:0370:7334
 192.0.2.128     ff02::1
 192.0.2.128     2001:0db8:0000:0000:0000:ff00:0042:8329
 192.0.2.128     ::
                 2001:0db8:0000:0000:0000:ff00:0042:8329
                 2001:db8:0:0:0:ff00:42:8329
                 2001:db8::ff00:42:8329
                 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001
                 ::1
                 fe80::
                 ::ffff:192.0.2.128
                 ::192.0.2.128
```

You can optimize the last piped `awk` with 2nd one, was not sure exactly how to do it. Otherwise, this works!

Comment: The output of time is the same.

Comment: I have updated the command without `tr` which might improve time, but that amount of delay is critical seriously?

Comment: When you have lots of lines of code, you consider using the fastest method. Thank you for answering my question.

Comment: @xToNouSou: Try my latest update and if this works better, do upvote/accept it

Comment: `paste "$FILE1" "$FILE2" | awk -F'\t' '{printf("%-15s %s\n",$1,$2)}'` is faster and works. Edit your answer to upvote.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the command `column`:

```
paste -d, file1 file2 | column  -s',' -n -t
```

The `paste` command will join both file line by line with the separator `,`.

The column command will replace the `,` by the necessary spaces to have it indented correctly (with option `-t`).
The `-n` is saying to `column` to fill empty column. *Note the option `-n`is Debian specific.*

Comment: `column: invalid option -- 'n'`, I do not have any Debian-based machine to test it out.